# instantiate an object within javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

```
**<%@ page import="com.ampliflex.commons.Ampliflex" %>**
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Result  </title>

<style>
img{ height: 150px; float: left; border: 3;}
div{font-size:10pt; margin-right:150px;
margin-left:150px; }
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  **Ampliflex ms = Ampliflex.getInstance();
  String mailHost = ms.getMailServer();**
// This function get the search results from Solr server 
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var query=getquerystring() ; //get the query string entered by user
```

Here in this, I imported a java class and instantiate its object. but object is not visible and script is generating an error "missing ; before statement
 Ampliflex ms = Ampliflex.getInstance();  "...i am not getting why so.

**EDIT:**

The problem is i need to access this mailHost with in javascript. if i instantiate object with in <%.. %> then mailHost is local variable and am not able to access in javascript tag. is there any solution for it.

Comment: you're trying to instantiate a server side Object from the client side, JS. think about it again.

Comment: Where (and when) does the Java run? Where (and when) does the JavaScript run? Therein lies the answer. The server-side *Java scriptlet* tags can emit JavaScript code. However, the *scriptlets run before* the HTML is sent to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate java object but, without a scriptlet

it should be some thing like

```
<%

  Ampliflex ms = Ampliflex.getInstance();
  String mailHost = ms.getMailServer();
%>
```

$(document).ready(function(){
  //Mail host
   var mailHost='<%= mailHost %>';

// This function get the search results from Solr server 
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var query=getquerystring() ;

And, if you want to invoke method after page is loaded, try using ajax.

Comment: is it not possible to instantiate object with in java script tag??

Comment: You cannot invoke directly ! You need to use applet or send a request to server !

Comment: The problem is i need to access this mailHost with in javascript. if i instantiate object with in <%.. %> then mailHost is local variable and am not able to access in javascript tag. is there any solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is this line:

```
Ampliflex ms = Ampliflex.getInstance();

  String mailHost = ms.getMailServer();
```

This is actually Java code.  This cannot execute on client side.  Use scriptlet tags.